# Gam: Why can't I use s(PTT, bs = "re") inside gamm?

Tags: r, mgcv

In the `mgcv` package, the `gamm` function can be used to model random effects.

In the usual `gam` function, we'd use

```
gam(y ~ s(Group, bs = "re")
```

But in `gamm`, we use:

```
gamm(y ~ 1, random = list(Group = ~1))
```

My question is: why can't we just use this below code inside `gamm` as well?

```
gamm(y ~ s(Group, bs = "re"))
```

It seems to work just fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that `gamm` models random effects by calling `lme` from the `nlme` package, so the syntax is the same as for that. If you call it with the `gam` syntax, then something different is happening.

Comment: So gamm does not treat even the smooth terms as gam does?

Comment: Well, the output of `summary(gam_model)` will look similar to that of `summary(gamm_model$gam)`, but not identical. You should use one or the other with the appropriate syntax.